# How to install php7.2-curl on a Debian 10? It depends on libcurl3 that is not available

Tags: debian, php, curl

I need `php7.2-curl`. But on Debian 10 `apt` says that it cannot be installed due to a dependency with `libcurl3`. But `libcurl3` cannot be installed (it gives me no reason).

Must I rollback to Debian 9.9?

I already tried to switch to PHP 7.3, but even `php7.3-curl` depends on `libcurl3`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [Ondrej Sury's repo](https://deb.sury.org/), I successfully installed `php7.3-curl` from it.
It seems that the version it proposes for `php7.2-curl` depends on `libcurl4` on Debian 10, which would make it work.

To install the repo for Debian 10, add

```
deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ buster main
```

to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or to a new `php.list` file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, then run

```
# apt update && apt upgrade
# apt install php7.2-curl
```

On my install, I'm getting this with Ondrej's repo:

```
# apt-cache depends php7.2-curl
php7.2-curl
  Dépend: php-common
  Dépend: ucf
  Dépend: php7.2-common
  Dépend: libc6
  Dépend: libcurl4
```

Comment: Hi ! Finally I tried on a server 'sacrificable'... When I try to add the repo, it suggest use ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline if I am using nginx... Is this a php repo or a nginx repo? - Anyway *I can confirm that your method works on debian 10.1. Please note that your 'edit2' step is absolutely a must*. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

If you want to install PHP 7.2, you’ll probably have to revert to Debian 9, yes. The `libcurl` transition is a rather complex one and it’s impossible to mix and match `libcurl3` and `libcurl4`-based packages; since Debian 10 uses `libcurl4`, you need to use packages depending on that. (Ondrej may well provide Debian 10-compatible PHP 7.2 packages at some point, I don’t know what the plans are.)

On Debian 10, you should be able to install PHP 7.3, [`php7.3-curl`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/php7.3-curl) depends on `libcurl4`. If you can’t, you’ve probably got conflicting repositories in your configuration; make sure you only attempt to install PHP packages from Debian itself.

Comment: Sorry to say that even php7.3 depends on libcurl3... But thanks, I rollbacked to debian 9.9

Comment: Did you follow the link? `php7.3` in Debian 10 most definitely does not depend on `libcurl3`. I have it installed on Debian 10 with no external repositories and it works fine.

Comment: I don not know why. My php7.3-curl needs libcurl3. I just downloaded official iso and retried on a clean vm. Sorry to says that. I read that for Debian the php7.x packages have been rebuild to allow both libcurl3 and 4. But i cannot see this relaxed config in the package

Comment: You installed from a Debian 10 ISO, then *without configuring any extra repositories*, you installed `php7.3-curl`, and it failed because it couldn’t find `libcurl3`?

Comment: Could you [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/529823/edit) to show the output of `apt policy php7.3-curl`?